# Combinations of list of list preserving list order to get chains

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of strings :

`answers = [['blue', 'green', 'orange'], ['yes', 'no'], ['saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them', 'continue'] ... ]`

It's from a quiz I want to work out all the combinations of answers to.

I know I could do the following to work out the different combinations to each individual answer

```
from itertools import combinations

q1 = list(combinations(answers[0], 1))
q2 = list(combinations(answers[1], 1))
q3 = list(combinations(answers[2], 3))
```

I'll then likely have to do list comprehension for the questions where there are multiple answers, but the answer `no` or `neither` is exclusive.

But I'm unclear how I could then combine these individual combinations into a larger chain, which preserves the order and still gives all the chains of answers.

This is part of a selenium project, where each item in the answer list would be clicked so preserving the variable names is important.

From the sample answers, chains would be:

```
chain 1 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['saturday', 'continue']]
chain 2 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['saturday', 'sunday', 'continue']]
chain 3 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend', 'continue']]
chain 4 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['saturday', 'weekend', 'continue']]
chain 5 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['weekend', 'sunday', 'continue']]
chain 6 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['sunday', 'continue']]
chain 7 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['weekend', 'continue']]
chain 8 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['continue']]
chain 9 = [['blue'], ['yes'], ['none of them']]
chain 10 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['saturday', 'continue']]
chain 11 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['saturday', 'sunday', 'continue']]
chain 12 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend', 'continue']]
chain 13 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['saturday', 'weekend', 'continue']]
chain 14 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['weekend', 'sunday', 'continue']]
chain 15 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['sunday', 'continue']]
chain 16 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['weekend', 'continue']]
chain 17 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['continue']]
chain 18 = [['blue'], ['no'], ['none of them']]
...
```

Comment: What would be the final output exactly? Also please include an input sample that can be copied directly into an IDE.

Comment: And why 1,1, and 4?

Comment: I've converted the example to strings, the variables are the result of several functions before. And  1, 1, and 3 because in question 3 the answers can be up to three of those answers combined (although the 'none of them' is exclusive)

Comment: Shouldn't this `q2 = list(combinations(lst[0], 1))` be `q2 = list(combinations(lst[1], 1))`?

Comment: Yes, sorry they should be indexed  - have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, are you not just looking to do a list comprehension through the combinations you already know? i.e.

```
[(q1_item, q2_item, q3_item) for q1_item in q1 for q2_item in q2 for q3_item in q3]
```

Or complete example:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> answers = [['blue', 'green', 'orange'], ['yes', 'no'], ['saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them', 'continue']]
>>> q1 = list(combinations(answers[0], 1))
>>> q1
[('blue',), ('green',), ('orange',)]
>>> q2 = list(combinations(answers[1], 1))
>>> q2
[('yes',), ('no',)]
>>> q3 = list(combinations(answers[2], 3))
>>> q3
[('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend'), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them'), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue'), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them'), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue'), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue'), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them'), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue'), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue'), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue')]
>>> [(q1_item, q2_item, q3_item) for q1_item in q1 for q2_item in q2 for q3_item in q3]
[(('blue',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('yes',), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('blue',), ('no',), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('green',), ('yes',), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('green',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend')), (('green',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them')), (('green',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue')), (('green',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('green',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('green',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('green',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('green',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('green',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('green',), ('no',), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('yes',), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'weekend')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'none of them')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'sunday', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('saturday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'none of them')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'weekend', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('sunday', 'none of them', 'continue')), (('orange',), ('no',), ('weekend', 'none of them', 'continue'))]
```

You could also add additional conditions to exclude certain combinations.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially doing a nested set of loops, one for each question, to create all the possible combinations:

```py
for a1 in combinations(lst[0], 1):
    for a2 in combinations(lst[1], 1):
        for a3 in combinations(lst[2], 3):
            print(a1, a2, a3)
```

That can get unwieldy pretty quickly. You can flatten the loop by using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to iterate over all the loops simultaneously.

```py
from itertools import combinations, product

q1 = combinations(lst[0], 1)
q2 = combinations(lst[1], 1)
q3 = combinations(lst[2], 3)

for a1, a2, a3 in product(q1, q2, q3):
    print(a1, a2, a3)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work but when it gets to around 35/40 questions it hangs (240GB memory 64 cores) any suggestions on efficiency improvements

Comment: @asparamancer The `itertools` calls use generators, so they should be fairly memory efficient.  35 questions, even if they only have 2 possible answers each, is still over 34 billion combinations.  If you're trying to store all those iterations simultaneously in memory, it will add up. Brute force iteration is always going to be inefficient.